# \LaTex in footnote

Tags: symbols, footnotes

I want to create a footnote, that say 'latex code has been taken from this source'. But I want standard latex symbol instead of a text 'latex'. How can I do it?
I have tried `$\LaTex$` and `\LaTex` , but those show undefined control sequence.

Comment: The "LaTeX" logo is obtained with `\LaTeX`, with three capitals: L, T, and X.  It doesn't require math.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess, you just made a typo (capital-X). The following code works for me.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,landscape]{memoir}

\begin{document}
I love \LaTeX.\footnote{\LaTeX\ code has been taken from this source.}
I also love \TeX.\footnote{\LaTeX{} code has been taken from this source.}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `pdfTeX`:

[image: d here]

---

To clarify: I posted an answer which completely satisfied the needs for the questioner. An edit was meant to improve the post but I forgot to compile it, hence I missed a bad spacing. Thank you, David Carlisle for pointing this out and correcting my error. The addition of `\` or `{}` gives the same results.

Comment: Perfect thank you! :)

Comment: A space after LaTeX would be nice:-)

Comment: I usually write e.g. `\LaTeX{}` to finish the command and keep the following space as-is.